# How to change title text and buttons color WITHOUT changing action overflow menu text color in new Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-styles, android-toolbar

I use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in my project. By default in light theme it has black action overflow menu icon, black title and black overflow menu text color, like that (don't look at the navigation icon - it's custom):

[image: Default Toolbar look like]
[image]

But in my App I need it to be white.
I set android:textColorPrimary to white in my styles for the toolbar:

```
<style name="Widget.My.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.My.Toolbar</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.My.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

It changed color of the title and the overflow menu button just like I wanted, but it changed Action owerflow menu items text color too:
[image]

It looks ugly.
I even tried set a Title color programmatically with

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources.getColor(R.color.white);
```

but it changes ONLY Title color, and not changes menu button:
[image]

So how can I change color for everything in the toolbar, except items in action overflow menu?

Comment: One of the best asked questions I have seen in a long while! +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you set the text color for for your `Toolbar` you can set the text color of your menus with the following attribute:

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
```

Since you are using the AppCompat `Toolbar` the android namespace need not be included in the attribute, as shown above.

However, it seems people have had mixed experience with this. You can also try using the `itemTextAppearance` attribute:

```
<style name="yourTheme" parent="yourThemeParent">
    <!-- Rest of your theme -->
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/menuItemColor</item>
</style>

<style name="menuItemColor">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

I found that the first solution worked for me when I explicitly included a `Toolbar` in my layout, but not if I used `getSupportActionBar()` to get the default bar included in a given theme. However, in this scenario, the second solution did work for me.

Comment: Setting actionMenuTextColor did nothing for me, but second solution did it! Thanks!!!